# "Constant expression required" on switch statements?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am working on switch statements. Java compiler tells me that a constant expression is required on my cases (x, y, z, a); Where is this coming from and why can't my code run the switch statement?

```
public class JavaPractice {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

        System.out.println("What's your happinessLevel? From 0 - 10");
        int _userHappinessLevel = IO.readInt();

        if ( _userHappinessLevel < 0 ) {
            x = _userHappinessLevel;
        } else if ( _userHappinessLevel <= 3) {
            y = _userHappinessLevel;
        } else if ( _userHappinessLevel > 3 && _userHappinessLevel <= 6 ) {
            z = _userHappinessLevel;
        } else if ( _userHappinessLevel > 6 && _userHappinessLevel <= 10) {
            a = _userHappinessLevel;
        } else {
            b = _userHappinessLevel;
        }


        switch (_userHappinessLevel) {

            case x:
                IO.reportBadInput();
                break;
            case y:
                System.out.println("Hope you feel better");
                break;
            case z:
                System.out.println("You're getting there");
                break;
            case a:
                System.out.println(":)");
                break;
            default:
                IO.reportBadInput();
                break;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.... your first set of `if`(s) guarantees that the label must be equal to `_userHappinessLevel`

Answer (score 0):

because the datatype of the   _userHappinessLevel   is int and when you put this variable in switch, the case should be numbers, or you can use enum to do things like give the string a "int "name.